# When to make ROOT the owner of Disks, Directories, Files

Tags: linux, root

I am just getting into Linux and am having problems with the subject of OWNERSHIP....
I seem to understand PERMISSIONS, GROUPS and USERS, but when it comes to setting OWNER I am confused as to when and why, you would set the owner of  a DISK, DIR/FOLDER, or FILE to "ROOT".
I would appreciate information on the "why and when"All I seem to find is the "HOW", and I can do that.
Thanks,
Anne

Comment: Unix permissions conventions http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

Comment: Thanks Knud.... I downloaded the file and started reading. A lot more than I wanted to know right now and a lot more indepth (I think) than my simple (?) question . I have already changed a few things based on what I have read so far, but I still do not see a "when" or "why" as it pertains to  my situation..  Many thanks for pointing me to the reference material....  Anne

Comment: »»  when and why, you would set the owner of a DISK, DIR/FOLDER, or FILE to "ROOT". «« : Happens automatically. Example, creating file or folder in `/home/[name]` : You are the owner. Usually `name:name`. To create in e.g. /usr/local/, you must su to "root", or use sudo. The owner will be `root:root`.

Comment: Disks : A plugged in usb key : Seems to be `name:name` . System disks : `root:root` .